# how to click on linktext which is already truncated a part of it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Screenshot]

I have a link text as shown above i am trying to find and click on it by using,

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Front printer (Based on price list) – UPDATE")).click();
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Front printer (Based on price list) – UPDATE1")).click();
```

The link text has been data driven from excel file (above just to show what is original link text i have posted it )
the issue is whenever it try to search it shows `nosuchelementexception()` . Since the link text is truncated some characters.

I cant use xpath since the element is dynamic it keeps changing its location in the list grid , and id keeps on changing so please suggest a way i need to select the element either linktext or partiallinktext.

HTML CODE IS

```
    <tr id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00__0" class="rgRow">

   < td align="left" style="width:3%;">

    <td align="left" style="width:45%;">

    <div style="float: left; width: 99%; overflow: hidden; height: 15px">

    <a href="http://192.168.1.6/eprint_prod_3.8/settings/digital_press_add.aspx?type=edit&    id=735" title="Front printer (Based on price list) - UPDATE">

    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_lblGuillotineName"    class="label_GV" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">Front printer (Based on price list) - UPDATE</span>

    </a>

    </div>

    </td>

    <td align="left" style="width:52%;">

   <td align="center" style="width:5%;">

    <td align="center" style="width:10%;">

   < /tr>
```

Comment: can you provide the html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the actual link text is truncated, search using a sub string using atleast the minimum number of characters required to get a unique match.

Note that with `By.partialLinkText`, *you* have to provide the partial text to search with, like so.

```
//assuming the below string is read from excel
String searchTxt = "Front printer (Based on price list) – ADD 1";
//try to search for the link using the first 30 chars
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(searchTxt.substring(0,30))).click();
```

The above code will return the first match it finds based on the partial text supplied.

Comment: Adding `import java.io.*;` at the top usually helps.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(CellVal.substring(0, 25)).click(); - showing error - The method click() is undefined for the type By

Comment: @Santhosh.S: Have already edited the code by adding a missing `)`. You should be able to catch and fix such errors yourself :)